# localhost 8443 refused to connect

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to install and run Apache Nifi in my windows laptop. using nifi 1.18.0.
I followed the steps and run the "run-nifi.bat" file. But on my browser,on running Nifi localhost 8443,it shows-This site can’t be reached . localhost refused to connect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You didn't configure the HTTPS part. Off topic.